# R is not rendering graph in forceDirect

Tags: r, d3.js, htmlwidgets, networkd3, d3-force-directed

Followed all the suggestions in Stackoverflow and YouTube but still cannot render graphs in networkD3 using R Studio.

Produced Nodes and Links csv files and uploaded same, simpleDirect is rendering from the Links file but forceDirect is both not indicating errors and not rendering graphs.

```r
library(networkD3)

Links <- 
  read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "
    Source  Target  Value
    A       B       1
    B       A       1
    AB      BA      1 
    A       C       1 
    C       A       1 
    AC      C       1
  ")

Nodes <- 
  read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "
    Id  Name  Group
    0   A     1
    1   B     1
    2   C     1
    3   AB    1
    4   AC    1
    5   BA    1
  ")

forceDirect(
  Links = Links, 
  Nodes = Nodes,
  Source = "Source", 
  Target = "Target",
  Value = "Value", 
  NodeId = "Name", 
  Group = "Group",
  opacity = 0
)
```

As stated previously, this (the Links data set) works well in simpleDirect but even though forceDirect calls errors, no graph is still being reproduced. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We can't help you without you providing us reproducible code and data.

Answer (score 0):

1. The function name is `forceNetwork()`, not `forceDirect()`.
2. The argument name is `NodeID`, not `NodeId`.
3. If you set the `opacity` argument to 0, you're not going to see anything.
4. The values in the `Source` and `Target` columns of the `Links` data frame  must be numeric, and identify the zero-indexed row of the `Nodes` data frame that they refer to.

```r
# your data
Links <- 
  read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "
    Source  Target  Value
    A       B       1
    B       A       1
    AB      BA      1 
    A       C       1 
    C       A       1 
    AC      C       1
  ")

Nodes <- 
  read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "
    Id  Name  Group
    0   A     1
    1   B     1
    2   C     1
    3   AB    1
    4   AC    1
    5   BA    1
  ")

# convert Source and Target to zero-indexed row of Nodes
Links$Source <- match(Links$Source, Nodes$Name) - 1
Links$Target <- match(Links$Target, Nodes$Name) - 1

# plot
library(networkD3)
forceNetwork(
  Links = Links, 
  Nodes = Nodes,
  Source = "Source", 
  Target = "Target",
  Value = "Value", 
  NodeID = "Name", 
  Group = "Group",
  opacity = 1
)
```

[image]