# R not rendering forceDirect graph

Tags: r, networkd3

Followed all the suggestions in Stackoverflow and YouTube but still cannot render graphs in networkD3 using R Studio.

Produced Nodes and Links csv files and uploaded same, simpleDirect is rendering from the Links file but forceDirect is both not indicating errors and not rendering graphs.

This is the data:

Links

Source Target Value A B 1 B A 1 AB BA 1 A C 1 C A 1 AC C 1

Nodes

Id Name Group 0 A 1 1 B 1 2 C 1 3 AB 1 4 AC 1 5 BA 1

Function:

````
```forceDirect(Links = Links, 
               Nodes = Nodes,
               Source = "Source", 
               Target = "Target",
               Value = "Value", 
               NodeId = "Name", 
               Group ="Group",
               opacity = 0.9)```
````

As stated previously, this (the Links data set) works well in simpleDirect but even though forceDirect calls errors, no graph is still being reproduced. Thanks in advance.

Followed all the suggestions online and literature. Nothing happened... no errors called but Links working fine in simpleNetwork.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R is not rendering graph in forceDirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75082670/r-is-not-rendering-graph-in-forcedirect)

Comment: Hello, thanks it worked... along the way I discovered that the datasets were constructed badly. Currently, everything's fine.